# What is a possible ordering of the vehicles serviced?

Tags: logical-deduction

A hatchback, a limousine, a pickup, a roadster, a sedan, and a van need service through the week - Monday through Saturday - one vehicle per day.

- At least one of the vehicles is serviced later in the week than the
  hatchback.
- The roadster is serviced later in the week than the van and earlier
  in the week than the hatchback.
- Either the pickup and the van are serviced on consecutive days, or
  the pickup and the sedan are serviced on consecutive days, but not
  both.
- The sedan is serviced earlier in the week than the pickup or earlier
  in the week than the limousine, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found

> van->pickup->roadster->sedan->hatchback->limousine
>  
> - At least one of the vehicles is serviced later in the week than the hatchback.**TRUE**
> - The roadster is serviced later in the week than the van and earlier in the week than the hatchback.**TRUE**
> - Either the pickup and the van are serviced on consecutive days, or the pickup and the sedan are serviced on consecutive days, but not both.**TRUE**
> - The sedan is serviced earlier in the week than the pickup or earlier in the week than the limousine, but not both.**TRUE**

Comment: Could you share how you set it up?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's several solutions. I have

> P -> S -> V -> R -> H -> L

From the clues:

- At least one of the vehicles is serviced later in the week than the hatchback.

> This just means that H cannot have the last space

- The roadster is serviced later in the week than the van and earlier in the week than the hatchback.

> This means that H, R, and V must be placed in the order  V -> R -> H (with maybe something in between each). Also, from this and the above it follows that neither H, R or V can take the last space. Neither R or V can take the second to last, and V cannot take the third to last.

- Either the pickup and the van are serviced on consecutive days, or the pickup and the sedan are serviced on consecutive days, but not both.

> This means taht P must be besides S or V, but not both. That is, the sequences V -> P -> S and V -> P -> S cannot exist, but P -> S -> V and V -> S -> P are fine.

- The sedan is serviced earlier in the week than the pickup or earlier in the week than the limousine, but not both.

> This means that we need either P -> S -> L or L -> S -> P (with something in between)

My solution is jsut the first think I tried that fulfilled the above.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Solutions:

> V->P->R->H->S->L
>  V->L->R->H->S->P
>  L->V->R->H->S->P
>  S->P->V->R->H->L
>  V->R->P->S->H->L

First start with a grid, days by cars, then cut out little pieces of paper, one each for each car, and move them around.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

> pickup->van->sedan->roadster->hatchback->limousine